# In AEM 6.2, how do you create a static page template on a site that already has editable page templates?

Tags: aem, sling

I'm having trouble creating a static page template on our site that already has editable pages. I'm not sure if I'm just creating the template wrong, missing a required call, or if config templates exist that AEM doesn't check for templates in apps.

I have my static template defined in apps, where [this documentation](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/develop/templates.html) says to define a static template

```
apps/<site-name>/templates/<template-name>
```

and my editable templates are in

```
content/conf/<site-name>/settings/wcm/templates
```

I've tried adding my static template to the conf templates directory, and it then shows up as an option when creating a new page, but the properties tab during page creation is empty and the create button is grayed out.

Here is my apps static template .content.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:mix="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/mix/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
          jcr:description="Bio Page"
          jcr:mixinTypes="[mix:lockable]"
          jcr:primaryType="cq:Template"
          jcr:title="Bio Page"
          allowedPaths="[/content(/.*)?]"
          ranking="{Long}3">
    <jcr:content
            cq:designPath="/etc/designs/<site>"
            jcr:primaryType="cq:PageContent"
            sling:resourceType="<site>/components/structure/static-page/bio"
            cq:template="/apps/<site>/templates/bio-page"> 
    </jcr:content>
</jcr:root>
```

Comment: Its not clear, what you want fixed. Do you want your static template working under /apps (the way pre 6.2 templates used to work) or you want it to be a configurable template using template editor?

Answer (score 0):

- Your static template not working when defined under `/apps/<site>/templates`, in your above XML for template definition the `jcr:content` shouldn't have property `cq:template`. The property `cq:template` exists in the pages created using the templates.

Where are you trying to create the page using your template, the template thou defines that allowed path as /content and any hierarchy below it but this may be limited/restricted by the properties `allowedChildren` and `allowedParents` on other templates in your hierarchy. Try creating a page directly under `/content` where no other limitation will apply. Are you able to create page then?

- Moving your template under `/conf/<site-name>/settings/wcm/templates` needs you to associate structure to it where in you define `sling:resourceType="<site>/components/structure/static-page/bio"`, this will be responsible for the defined properties that you see in the create page wizard. If reused/copy pasted the template from `/apps` to `/conf` then you may be missing this structure, adding which will fix the issue

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your sling:resourceType path is 100% correct. The case of the `sling:resourceType` property on jcr:content is case sensitive, so make sure you've verified the case matches in the path as well.

I have seen this same problem (AEM 6.2).

In

```
/apps/<site>/templates/<templatename>/jcr:content
```

I had a typo in the `sling:resourceType` property.

I had entered the  name with incorrect case (`mySite` vs `mysite`).

Correcting the path resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

By default, if you created your editable template through the UI, as opposed to coding it by hand, and then proceeded to create the site's root page using this template, the editable template and hence the site's root page will have a very restrictive `cq:allowedTemplates` value, such as `/conf/mysite/settings/wcm/templates/.*`. To allow static templates to co-exist with the editable template on the same site, you'll need to add `/apps/mysite/components/templates/.*` to the editable template's `cq:allowedTemplates`.